# What is the meaning of "votes" in the profile dropdown for per-site-meta

Tags: support, per-site-meta, activity-dropdown

Profile dropdown on Meta of all Stack Exchange sites (except Meta Stack Overflow), displays **votes** and **votes cast**. What number is displayed in the **votes** row?

> [image]

All the main sites (and Meta Stack Overflow) display *reputation* instead of *votes*.

> [image]

I understand that reps on [per-meta-sites](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/per-site-meta/info) are same as on the corresponding main site, so *reputation* is not shown but what is the first *votes* record?

Comment: My guess is those are the votes you **received** on Meta posts (since reputation is shared between meta and main site). Did you get any votes on any meta site recently to check this?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd my dropdown at Programmers meta appears to reflect votes I've got recently there: [activity dropdown screen shot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/im4Q0.png)

Comment: @gnat thanks, that's proof enough for me. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those appear to be the votes you *received* on your Meta posts.

Since reputation is shared between meta and main site, there is no point showing the reputation earned, so something unique to the meta site is displayed instead.

Comment: Votes or score? Also, is this mentioned in any post or faq?

Comment: @Aziz well, as it's not separated to upvotes/downvotes I would say score, meaning it can be negative. Didn't find and official mentioning of this just yet.